# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read' while reading .gz file from GCS in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

This is not a duplicate post

I am facing  below issue while reading a .gz(zip) file from  GCS bucket in python

file name  :**ABC.dat.gz**

**content = downloaded_blob.read () .
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'**

code :

```py
    blob = bucket.blob('sftp/poc/ABC.dat.gz')
    downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string() 
    print(downloaded_blob)    
    content = downloaded_blob.read () 
    buff = BytesIO (content) # put    content into file object 
    f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buff) 
    print('Lots    of content here 8') 
    res = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    print(res)
```

Comment: your downloading  the blob as a bytes object. byte type doesnt have any method called read so thats why you get the error. what are you trying to read? you have alread read the blob into a bytes object

Comment: thanks Chris . Actually i am trying to read the .gz file from GCS and  print the contents inside it

Comment: but you dont have a file object here, you have a bytes object. Maybe you want to download the zip file first then unzip it. https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_to_file

Comment: Thanks Chirs , I am trying to download the file but its not happening , Can you help to me modify the above code

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you want to achieve globally, but I think at least you can get rid of this error. First of all, according to [the docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#) method `download_as_string` is:

> (Deprecated) Download the contents of this blob as a bytes object.
>
> **Note:**
>
> Deprecated alias for download_as_bytes().

So you should use this method instead.

If I understand correctly, you need to have `Bytes` objects to create `BytesIO`. For this you do not have to do any action on the `downloaded_blob` variable as it's already in proper type. So the code that should work looks like here:

```
blob = bucket.blob('sftp/poc/ABC.dat.gz')
downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_bytes() 
print(downloaded_blob)    
buff = BytesIO (downloaded_blob) # put    content into file object 
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buff) 
print('Lots    of content here 8') 
res = f.read().decode('utf-8')
print(res)
```

Comment: Hi @ Wytrzymały Wiktor  ,@vitooh , i tried putting this logic in cloud function and execute it .it gives me below error. . most of time i am getting this error.
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'blob'"

Comment: If this error is referring to presented code the problem must be with initialization of `bucket`. This is outside of this code sample. As this is different problem I suggest to create new question adding this part of the code.

Comment: @vitooh  thanks for the response .Now i am able to read the data . Can you please tell how i can upload printed data to bucket

Comment: just ask new question, I do not always have time, but there are a lot of people who can help on SO